# How to multithreading this jobs?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My idea is if finished download this messages then add them to ListView. But if this code we will waiting very long and program will be not responding. Can you help me?

```
private void MailTree_AfterSelect(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)
{          
    MailList.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < client.Folders.Count; i++)
    {                          
        (ContextMenuListView.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems[i].Click += new EventHandler(MainForm_Click);
    }
    if (MailTree.SelectedNode.Text == Username)
    {
        webBrowser1.Visible = false;//webBrowser1.DocumentText = "Hello Baby";
        AttachmentList.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser1.Visible = true;
        groupBox1.Visible = true;

        try
        {
            messages = client.Folders[MailTree.SelectedNode.Text].Search("ALL", false); // Search mail in your choossen Folder
            AmoutOfMail = messages.Count(); //Amout of Mail in this Folder                                         
            for (int i = 0; i < AmoutOfMail; i++)
            {
                mes = messages[i];

                SaveMail(mes); // dowload mes and store message

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                Mime m = EncodingMail(MailTree.SelectedNode.Text, mes); // read mes from place store message
                item.Text = mes.MessageUid.ToString();
                item.SubItems.Add(m.MainEntity.Subject);
                ReturnMime(m);
                if (mailfromname != null)
                    item.SubItems.Add(mailfromname);
                else 
                    item.SubItems.Add(mailfrom);
                item.SubItems.Add(m.MainEntity.Date.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(mailfrom);
                MailList.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }                                         
        catch (Exception)
        { }                                                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Look into the [`Tasks` library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to offload whatever you want onto a different thread.

Just make sure that you use [`Controls.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) to place the callback code back onto the UI thread. You should never modify the UI from a different thread than the UI thread.